# PowerQuery: Force Lowercase for an alphanumeric Text

Tags: powerquery, alphanumeric

How are you able to force an alphanumeric string to lowercase (or uppercase) in powerQuery?

I have a series of attribute codes coming into powerQuery , but the codes contain variations of
upper case and lower case text. In practice these items would be considered duplicates, but PowerQuery is case sensitive. I've tried using Text.lower / Text.upper but this requires the data to be type text. My data is alphanumeric (123abc, 111, aaa) and text functions do not work for data *type any*

Suggestions?
description below:

```
' Activity       Activity ID'

  Apple          1CA11
  Apple          1ca11
  Orange         2dp23
  Orange         2DP23

'This should become: 
  Apple          1ca11
  Orange         2dp23
```

Picture below:
[image: Error Example using Text.lower]

[image: Removing Duplicates]

Comment: I'll bite -- why won't you convert the type to Text to do the operation? Or convert type, change case, then convert type back

Comment: Is there a reason you can't convert the field to text? You can always convert it back to alphanumeric after you filter out the dupes?

Comment: @horseyride & Bryan Rock, 
Yes. The issue lies in the fact that there are also exclusive numbers in the column of alphanumeric values. ex. 10683 can't be converted to text. 

I tried converting the bulk to text, forcing lowercase then removing duplicates and reverting to type any, but that is what results in my current error.

Comment: I'll add that it comes in via an excel document into powerQuery. If it were SQL into PowerQuery there would be ways to change into before coming in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ignore case of just the Activity ID field in Table.Distinct operations

```
= Table.Distinct(Source,{{"Activity", Comparer.Ordinal}, {"Activity ID", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase}} )
```

or ignore case in all columns in the Table.Distinct

```
= Table.Distinct(Source, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Bryan Rock and Horsey Ride. I had a total goof up. The issue was in not ordering a change type prior (Looks like the original step got deleted).

Thanks for the help!
Changing type before forcing lower/uppercase solves the problem.

Comment: Please don't use answers use comments for messages like that.